# Suppressing logout msg ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, bashrc, logout

I have added several lines to be executed in systemwide `/etc/bash.bashrc` such as notifying a login via email, etc. I have noticed that upon `exit` which invokes `logout`, systems prints those lines to the users as :

```
USER@IP:~$ exit
logout
[1]+  Done                    cat /home/USER/a.txt | ssmtp EMAIL@gmail.com
Connection to IP closed.
```

How can I suppress this on my system?

Comment: Can you add your additions to your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file to your question, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[1]+  Done ...` part of your output seems to come from Bash's job control. You usually get it when a command that you have started in background terminates, like this:

```
$ sleep 1 &
[1] 20931

$ 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
```

---

One solution to suppress these job control outputs is to launch the background command in a subshell, by enclosing it in parentheses:

```
$ ( sleep 1 &)

$
```

I can't tell whether this is appropriate in your situation, because you haven't shown your actual commands yet and this approach comes with a few disadvantages:

The job can't be controlled any more (e.g. `jobs`, `bg`, `fg` commands), but as it runs from a startup script, I assume that wouldn't be intended anyway.
If the command were modifying its environment (e.g. setting variables or changing the working directory), that would only affect the subshell then and no longer the rest of the script.

---

Another way is to make the shell forget about the job after it started using `disown`, like:

```
$ sleep 1 & disown
[1] 27248

$
```

That way however, it will also no longer terminate when the shell exits, so it might keep running past the user logout, if I understood this right (correct me if not).

---

Sources and further reading:

- [Running bash commands in the background without printing job and process ids](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7686989/4464570)
- [Is there a way to make bash job control quiet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11097761/4464570)
- [How to /dev/null background processes “informational” output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26534/103151)
- [How to suppress exit code of finished background jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/225201/103151)